# How to pass a specific array element to a modal in react?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog

In my `PoolListItem.jsx` I have a table component with information of devices. However since I have a lot of information I want to display the less important ones on a modal when I click on a button. The body of the table looks like this inside a return:

```
<tbody>
        {
          deviceMonitoringEntries.map((entry) => (
            <tr className={Styles.device}>
              <td className={Styles.device_name}>
                {entry.deviceDescriptor.id}
              </td>
              <td>
                {entry.deviceDescriptor.osVersion ? entry.deviceDescriptor.osVersion : ' '}
              </td>
              <td>
                {entry.deviceDescriptor.apiLevel ? entry.deviceDescriptor.apiLevel : ' '}
              </td>
              <td>
                {entry.devicePoolStateEntry.details.serial ? `${entry.devicePoolStateEntry.details.serial}` : '  ' }
              </td>
              <td className={Styles.icon_btn}>
                <OverlayTrigger
                  delay={300}
                  overlay={(
                    <Tooltip id={`app-group-list-view-app-name-${entry.deviceDescriptor.id}-tooltip`}>
                      <span> Device Information</span>
                    </Tooltip>
                  )}
                  placement="top"
                  rootClose
                >
                  <span>
                    <IconButton
                      category="action"
                      icon={<IconInformationFill />}
                      onPress={() => dispatch(modalActions.showModal(DEVICE_INFO_MODAL),
                      )}
                      size="sm"
                      variant="text"
                    />
                    <DeviceInfoModal
                      {...console.log(entry)}
                      entry={entry}
                    />
                  </span>
                </OverlayTrigger>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))
        }
      </tbody>
```

Although I pass one entry to the modal as in

```
<DeviceInfoModal
    {...console.log(entry)}
    entry={entry}
/>
```

It seems to go over the list and print each and every single modal for each device when I click on the button which results in displaying the modal of the last item in the array. I tried setting the state with elements but no luck. My modal looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Button from '@saucelabs/sl-component-buttons';
import modalConnect from '@saucelabs/sl-container-modal';
import { Modal } from '@saucelabs/sl-component-overlay';
import { Row, Col } from '@saucelabs/sl-component-grid';
import { DebouncedInput } from '@saucelabs/sl-component-form';
import Label from '@saucelabs/sl-component-label';

import * as constants from '../constants';
import Styles from '../containers/PoolsContainer';

const banUserFormHandler = { submit: null };

const DeviceInfoModal = ({
  id, onFormSubmit, onHide, show, entry,
}) => (
  <Modal
    entry={entry}
    show={show}
  >
    <Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Title className="text-primary"><h2>Device Information</h2></Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>
      <Row>
        <Col xs={12}>
          <DebouncedInput
            label="Serial"
            {...console.log("DeviceInfoModal")}
            {...console.log(entry)}
            placeholder={entry.devicePoolStateEntry.details.serial ? `${entry.devicePoolStateEntry.details.serial}` : '  '}
          />
          <DebouncedInput
            label="API Version"
            {...console.log("DeviceInfoModal")}
            {...console.log(entry)}
            placeholder={entry.deviceDescriptor.apiLevel ? entry.deviceDescriptor.apiLevel : ' '}
          />
          <DebouncedInput
            label="Battery"
            {...console.log("DeviceInfoModal")}
            {...console.log(entry)}
            placeholder={entry.devicePoolStateEntry.details.battery ? `${entry.devicePoolStateEntry.details.battery.level} - ${entry.devicePoolStateEntry.details.battery.status}% -  ${entry.devicePoolStateEntry.details.battery.health}` : ' '}
          />
          <DebouncedInput
            label="Memory"
            {...console.log("DeviceInfoModal")}
            {...console.log(entry)}
            placeholder={{}}
          />
          <Col>
            <Label
              category="info"
              className={Styles.label}
            >
              <Row around="xs">
                <Col
                  className={Styles.property}
                  xs
                >
                  <span>Serial:&nbsp;</span>
                  <span className={Styles.value}>
                    {entry.devicePoolStateEntry.details.serial ? `${entry.devicePoolStateEntry.details.serial}` : '  '}
                  </span>
                </Col>
                <Col
                  className={Styles.property}
                  xs
                >
                  <span>API Level:&nbsp;</span>
                  <span className={Styles.value}>
                    {entry.deviceDescriptor.apiLevel ? entry.deviceDescriptor.apiLevel : ' '}
                  </span>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Label>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <Label
              category="info"
              className={Styles.label}
            >
              <Row around="xs">
                <Col
                  className={Styles.property}
                  xs
                >
                  <span>Battery:&nbsp;</span>
                  <span className={Styles.value}>
                    {entry.devicePoolStateEntry.details.battery ? `${entry.devicePoolStateEntry.details.battery.level} - ${entry.devicePoolStateEntry.details.battery.status}% -  ${entry.devicePoolStateEntry.details.battery.health}` : ' '}
                  </span>
                </Col>
                <Col
                  className={Styles.property}
                  xs
                >
                  <span>Memory:&nbsp;</span>
                  <span className={Styles.value}>
                    { 'no info ' }
                  </span>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Label>
          </Col>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer>
      <Button
        category="default"
        material
        onClick={onHide}
        size="sm"
      >
        Cancel
      </Button>
      <Button
        category="action"
        material
        onClick={() => banUserFormHandler.submit()}
        size="sm"
      >
        Submit
      </Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
  </Modal>
);

DeviceInfoModal.propTypes = {
  entry: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  id: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.number,
    PropTypes.string,
  ]).isRequired,
  onFormSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onHide: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  show: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};

export default modalConnect(constants.DEVICE_INFO_MODAL, DeviceInfoModal);
export { DeviceInfoModal };
```

How can I pass only one specific entry in an array as an argument to a modal when I click on a button?

Answer (score 0):

The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
const array1 = [1, 4, 9, 16];

// pass a function to map
const map1 = array1.map(x => x * 2);

console.log(map1);
// expected output: Array [2, 8, 18, 32]
```

With:

```
deviceMonitoringEntries.map((entry) => (
...
<DeviceInfoModal
    {...console.log(entry)}
    entry={entry}
/>
...
)
```

You are doing the same. Returning a `DeviceInfoModal` with the respective entry for  each `entry`.
To have unique `DeviceInfoModal` you need to have outside of the `map` function and pass yuor `index` of interest.

```
<DeviceInfoModal
    {...console.log(entry)}
    entry={deviceMonitoringEntries[index]}
/>
```

Comment: but then how can I access the index outside of the map? @rustyBucketBay

Comment: if you passed is as a prop through the parent, is should be available on `props.deviceMonitoringEntries`

Comment: I am trying to pass it as a prop to modal as you suggested with `<DeviceInfoModal
    entry={deviceMonitoringEntries[index]}
/>` outside of the map function but inside the `<tbody>`, which should be triggered by the button but the index is not defined at this moment so I tried to use state by `const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);` and set index to entry inside the button ` <IconButton
                      onPress={() => dispatch(modalActions.showModal(DEVICE_INFO_MODAL),
                        setIndex(entry),
                      )}
                    /> ` @rustyBucketBay